# Difference between SomeValue {get;} = true; vs SomeValue => true; in Properties

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In C# you could declare a property in two ways that seem very similar:

```
public string SomeProperty => "SomeValue";
```

vs

```
public string SomeProperty { get; } = "SomeValue";
```

Is there a difference between these two? (Ignoring the fact that "SomeValue" is not a very interesting value, it could be the result of a method call or whatever else would express a difference between the two forms).

Comment: The first is a `get` that returns a hard-coded string, the second has a backing field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example there is no functional difference because you're always returning a constant value.  However if the value could change, e.g.

```
public string SomeProperty => DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

vs

```
public string SomeProperty { get; } = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The first would execute the expression each time the property was called.  The second would return the same value every time the property was accessed since the value is set *at initialization*.

In pre-C#6 syntax the equivalent code for each would be

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return DateTime.Now.ToString();}
}
```

vs

```
private string _SomeProperty = DateTime.Now.ToString();
public string SomeProperty 
{ 
    get {return _SomeProperty;} 
}
```

Comment: It's vice versa: the first will execute the expression each time; the second will return the same value.

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks, fixed.  I realized I had it backwards when I started adding the pre-C#6 equivalent.